# invoking stored proc/fun from trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I wrote one trigger and SP in MySQL, both are working fine separately.
when I call SP from trigger it is throwing an error.

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'name' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

The trigger is `BEFORE UPDATE ON SP` is updating the same table, but different row.

Comment: The error really tells you all. You can't work around it sadly.

Comment: N.B. : This is true even for latest version of mysql?  If it is possible, we are happy to migrate/move to newer version of mysql.

Comment: It is true for the latest version as well, and if you think about it - you update a table from trigger, it triggers the before update trigger, it updates the table - triggers the trigger and you get a nice infinite loop. Maybe if you explained what you're trying to do -there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: Our table is having interlinked data, so when some field in some row changes, it will need to get reflect in other fields in other row in same table.

Comment: Is it possible for you to adjust the schema so you can store certain data in another table and update the other table which in turn updates the source table?